# Cmake, finding a header file in /usr/local/include and library in /usr/local/lib

Tags: c++, cmake

I want CMake to find the header for add_executable and find the .so file for target_link_libraries.

The header file I want to find is lcm-cpp.hpp (on ubunthu)

```
ls /usr/local/include/lcm/
eventlog.h  lcm_coretypes.h  lcm-cpp.hpp  lcm-cpp-impl.hpp  lcm.h
```

The CMakeLists.txt file in the root of my project

```
 cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
 project (libFoo)
 include_directories(include /usr/local/include/lcm/)

 set(PROJECT_SRC
     src/Foo.cpp )

 set(PROJECT_H
     include/Foo.hpp )

 find_library(LCM_LIBRARY
     NAMES liblcm.so
     PATHS
     /usr/local/lib/
 )

add_library(liblcm STATIC IMPORTED)

add_library(foo_lib ${PROJECT_SRC} ${PROJECT_H})

add_executable(foo_lcm src/lcm_foo.cpp ${PROJECT_H} lcm-cpp.hpp)
```

The error I get:

```
  Cannot find source file:

  lcm-cpp.hpp

 Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
 .hxx .in .txx
```

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear. Can you elaborate? Wild guess: are you perhaps looking for [`include_directories`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:include_directories) and passing a full path to `target_link_libraries`?

Comment: @Angew include_directories(include /usr/local/include) does not work (I have a directory ./include for my own header files)

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/): a minimal CMakeList & source code which demonstrates the problem, post your header file locations & any errors you are getting (compiler errors, I assume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CMake command `include_directories()` is used for specifying additional directories where the *compiler* should search for `#include`d files. It does not affect CMake's search for source files at all.

If the file `/usr/local/include/lcm/lcm-cpp.hpp` is really a part of your executable (you'd want it listed in the project in Visual Studio, for example), you'll have to specify it with the full path:

```
add_executable(foo_lcm src/lcm_foo.cpp ${PROJECT_H} /usr/local/include/lcm/lcm-cpp.hpp)
```

However, based on its location, it looks more like a library external to your executable. If that's the case, it should not be listed in `add_executable()` at all.